# Passing a subpath as a variable (type of node) or either eval() an string containing a relative XPATH

Tags: sorting, xpath, uri, eval, xquery

I want to succed with following functionality, and it works if you harcoded it:

```
declare function local:sort($collection as node()*, $filter as xs:SUBPATH?) as node()*{
     for $element in $collection
     order by 
        if ($filter) then ($element/$filter) (: OR SOME KIND OF fn:eval($filter) IF WE DEFINED $filter AS AN xs:string :)
        else              ($element/name()) (: Default :)
     descending
     return $element
};
```

And it could be called like that:

```
for $element in local:sort(doc('data')/Data/*,'/@myAttr')
return $element
```

or

```
for $element in local:sort(doc('data')/Data/*,'/subnode/subnode/name()')
return $element
```

or

```
for $element in local:sort(doc('data')/Data/*,()) (: This is the default of function = own elment´s name :)
return $element
```

Mx problem is passing the subpath. Either I need to know some kind of way to send a relative XPATH as an argument and type of node, or I need some kind of eval to pass from xs:string to a runtime valid code

Any help?

Comment: Just wait for XPath 3.0 and you'll be able to pass a function for the second argument. There might be also dynamic evaluation of the kind you are asking for -- like `<xsl:evaluate>` in XSLT 3.0 -- http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#element-evaluate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider (a) generating a query in which the filter is hard-coded, or (b) using an eval() function specific to your XQuery vendor, or (c) using XQuery 3.0 higher-order functions if your chosen XQuery engine supports them yet.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following, thanks to this idea [How can I solve this autoncremental var case in XQUERY 1.0 FLOWR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816437/how-can-i-solve-this-autoncremental-var-case-in-xquery-1-0-flowr/11816876#11816876):

```
(: This is a workaround solution as xquery:eval() is not working with var bindings until BaseX 7.3 version :)
(: It evals $context node + literal subpath with a pattern of '(/)lit/lit/lit/@attr' or '(/)lit/lit/lit' representing (/)lit/lit/lit/name(). If subpath null, it returns $context/name().:) 
declare function u:eval-path($context as node()*, $subnodes as xs:string*) as item()* {
  if(empty($subnodes)) then $context/name()
  else(
    if (count($subnodes) eq 1) then ( (: Last Element :)
               if (starts-with($subnodes[1],'@')) then $context/@*[name()=substring-after($subnodes[1],'@')]
                   else $context/*[name()=$subnodes[1]]/name()
         )   
    else if ($subnodes[1] eq '') then u:eval-path($context, $subnodes[position() gt 1])
    else u:eval-path($context/*[name()=$subnodes[1]],$subnodes[position() gt 1])
   )
};


(: Sorts the given collection by given criteria, which should be a pattern '(/)lit/lit/lit/@attr' or '(/)lit/lit/lit' representing (/)lit/lit/lit/name() :)
(: If criteria is null, everything is ordered by $elements/name(). Theres no way to filter intermediate nodes as in /lit/*[name()='X']/lit :)
declare function u:sort($collection as node()*, $criteria as xs:string?) as node()*{
    for $element in $collection
    order by u:eval-path($element,tokenize($criteria,'/'))
    ascending
    return $element
};
```