# How can I solve this autoncremental var case in XQUERY 1.0 FLOWR?

Tags: xml, xpath, for-loop, xquery

Pseudocode would be something like:

```
 let $myNode as node() := $node 
 for $subpath in tokenize($path,'/')
 $myNode := $myNode/*[name()=$subpath] (: Here is the invalid line :)
```

I know there is a operator for this in xQuery 3.0, I am asking for xQuery 1.0.

Comment: As far as I know there has never been a XQuery 2.0. The current version of XQuery is 1.0 and its successor (in development) is XQuery 3.0 (previously named XQuery 1.1). Maybe you are confused with XPath or XSLT, which both are at version 2.0?

Comment: Corrected, thanks. Some xQuery 3.0 features are already included in engines as saxon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no *XQuery 2.0*, but what you want to do isn't possible only with a *FLWOR* expression regardless of version. The set of current nodes would have to be updated between iterations, which isn't how *FLWOR* expressions work.

That said, what you want to do is easily possible with a recursive function in **XQuery 1.0**:

```
declare function local:path(
  $context as node()*,
  $steps as xs:string*
) as node()* {
  if(empty($steps)) then $context
  else local:path(
    $context/*[name() = $steps[1]],
    $steps[position() gt 1]
  )
};
```

You can call it with  `local:path(document{ <x><y>foo</y><z/></x> }, tokenize("x/y", '/'))`.

In **XQuery 3.0** it's even easier to do, without a new top-level function:

```
fn:fold-left(
  function($context, $step) {
    $context/*[name() eq $step]
  },
  document{ <x><y>foo</y><z/></x> },
  tokenize('x/y', '/')
)
```

The function [fn:fold-left(..)](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-fold-left) takes care of the recursion internally and you only have to specify how to modify the context set in each step.